# conflict JS Jquery

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I Purchased a magento theme named `em everything` After installing i m having some problems, 1 add to cart not working, 2 ccevenue plugin not woring in one page checkout, so i messaged the theme seller and they replied this

> Cause of the error is due conflict JS Jquery. Because you have install extension of 3rd party.
>
> Please remove load Jquery library from extension : IWD , Magebuzz :
>
> - http://www.sharpdeal.net/js/iwd/all/iwd-jquery-2.1.3.min.js
> - http://www.sharpdeal.net/js/magebuzz/testimonial/jquery/jquery.min.js

My Question is how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they replied seems you need to remove some jquery

http://www.sharpdeal.net/js/iwd/all/iwd-jquery-2.1.3.min.js

http://www.sharpdeal.net/js/magebuzz/testimonial/jquery/jquery.min.js

That may be because the theme seller already added jquery in there extension & multiple definitions giving conflicts.

Need some code level experience:

1. Find out the layout(.xml) file of the third party module they mentioned.
2. Remove the JS definition from there.

Comment: Thank u, i removed the jquerys as u said..but still add to cart not working, can u check and figure out whats the problem?? @akhilgupta

Comment: I found: There is error in file :
/home/sharpdea/public_html/app/code/local/Magpleasur/Richsnippets/Block/Catalog/Product/View/Markup.php on line  32

Comment: Error is "Call to a member function getId()"

Comment: i just removed this plugin and problem solved ad to cart is working...thank uu